# Packaged Kivy app visually incorrect

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller

I have a simple table app that I packaged with Pyinstaller for os x. If I run `main.py`, the widget displays correctly:

[image: Correct view]

After packaging the app in accordance with the [docs](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-osx.html) and open the `.app` the sizing of the labels etc. are messed up. In fact, if there were other widgets those too would not be sized correctly.

[image]

Is there a problem with my `kv` or code in general that maybe causing this? I have a large app that I've been trying to package for a week and I've gotten things down to this one last bit.

Other info: I'm on Mac Yosemite. I can provide logs if need be, but I don't see any errors in them.

Here's `main.py`

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = """
<Cell>:
    size_hint: (None, None)
    width: 400
    height: 60
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: [0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 1] if self.is_even else [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1]
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<Table>:
    grid: grid
    bar_width: 25
    scroll_type: ['bars', 'content']
    bar_color: [0.4, 0.7, 0.9, 1]
    bar_inactive_color: [0.2, 0.7, 0.9, .5]
    do_scroll_x: True
    do_scroll_y: True
    GridLayout:
        id: grid
        cols: 15
        rows: 30
        size_hint: (None, None)
        width: self.minimum_width
        height: self.minimum_height
"""

Builder.load_string(kv)


class Cell(Label):
    is_even = BooleanProperty(None)


class Table(ScrollView):

    grid = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Table, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for i in range(30):
            for j in range(15):
                text = "data row: {}, column: {}".format(i, j)
                self.grid.add_widget(Cell(text=text, is_even=i % 2 is 0))


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Table()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to use dp or sp with your sizes. See https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.metrics.html

Comment: Thanks! I think that was the issue. Make an answer and I'll mark it if you'd like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to use `dp` or `sp` with your sizes. See [kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.metrics.html](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.metrics.html)